# The method of the right DQL in Symfony2 : Relationship has been recursive

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3, dql

Simple view of Data Structure:

My\ExampleBundle\Entity\Parent:

```
oneToMany:
    children:
        targetEntity: Children
        mappedBy    : parent
        cascade     : ["persist", "remove"]
manyToMany:
    friends:
      targetEntity  : Friend
      inversedBy    : parents
      cascade       : ["persist"]
      joinTable     :
        name        : my_parents_and_friends
        joinColumns :
            joinColum:
                name                : parent_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                onDelete            : CASCADE
        inverseJoinColumns:
            joinColum:
                name                : friend_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                onDelete            : CASCADE
```

.

My\ExampleBundle\Entity\Children:

```
manyToOne:
    parent:
        targetEntity: Parent
        inversedBy  : children
        joinColumn  :
            name                : parent_id
            referencedColumnName: id
manyToMany:
    friends:
      targetEntity  : Friend
      inversedBy    : children
      cascade       : ["persist"]
      joinTable     :
        name        : my_children_and_friends
        joinColumns :
            joinColum:
                name                : children_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                onDelete            : CASCADE
        inverseJoinColumns:
            joinColum:
                name                : friends_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                onDelete            : CASCADE
```

.

My\ExampleBundle\Entity\Friend:

```
manyToOne:
    school:
        targetEntity: My\SchoolBundle\Entity\School
        inversedBy  : friends
        joinColumn  :
            name                : school
            referencedColumnName: id
manyToMany:
    parents:
        targetEntity: Parent
        mappedBy    : friends
    children:
        targetEntity: Children
        mappedBy    : friends
```

.

My\SchoolBundle\Entity\School:

```
oneToMany:
    friends:
        targetEntity: My\ExampleBundle\Entity\Friend
        mappedBy    : school
        cascade     : ["persist", "remove"]
```

.

---

So this is a usually my way of query.

```
public function findOneParent($id)
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
        SELECT
            p,
            pf,  pfg,  pfsch,
            ch,  chg,
            chf, chfg, chfsch

        FROM MyExampleBundle:Parent     p

        LEFT JOIN p.friends             pf
            WITH //...
            LEFT JOIN pf.groups         pfg
            LEFT JOIN pf.school         pfsch

        LEFT JOIN p.children            ch
            WITH //...
            LEFT JOIN ch.groups         chg

        LEFT JOIN ch.friends            chf
            WITH //...
            LEFT JOIN chf.groups        chfg
            LEFT JOIN chf.school        chfsch

        WHERE p.id = :id
    ')
    ->setParameter('id',   $id);

    return $this->try_catch($query);
}
```

_

```
Parent: AAA
    related: children BBB
    related: friends  CCC

Children: BBB
    related: parent  AAA
    related: friends CCC

Friend: CCC
    related: parent   AAA
    related: children BBB
```

_

get parent AAA's data with relationship:

```
parent AAA
    |- children BBB
    |   |- friends CCC
    |
    |- friends CCC
```

_

It seems that the data of 'parent.children.friends.groups' duplicates.

```
{{ parent.name }}
    {% for child in parent.children %}
        {{ child.name }}

        {% for friend in child.friends %}
            {{ friend.name }}

            {% for group in friend.groups %}
                {{ group.name }}    // = echo twice same value ...??
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

I am confused.
Is my DQL wrong?

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

---

### EDIT: For Example:

friend Mr.CCC

Mr. CCC is a member of the 'first' group and 'second' group.

now:

```
{{ parent.name }}
    {% for child in parent.children %}
        {{ child.name }}

        {% for friend in child.friends %}
            {{ friend.name }} // friend = Mr. CCC

            {% for group in friend.groups %}  // {{ friend.groups | length }} = 4...why?
                {{ group.name }}    // = echo : first first second second
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for friend in parent.friends %}
        {{ friend.name }} // friend = Mr. CCC

        {% for group in friend.groups %}  // {{ friend.groups | length }} = 4...why?
            {{ group.name }}    // = echo : first first second second
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

.

It should be like this:

```
{{ parent.name }}
    {% for child in parent.children %}
        {{ child.name }}

        {% for friend in child.friends %}
            {{ friend.name }} // friend = Mr. CCC

            {% for group in friend.groups %}  // {{ friend.groups | length }} = 2
                {{ group.name }}    // = echo : first second
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for friend in parent.friends %}
        {{ friend.name }} // friend = Mr. CCC

        {% for group in friend.groups %}  // {{ friend.groups | length }} = 2
            {{ group.name }}    // = echo : first second
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Not sure about your problem, {{ friend.groups }} contains two groups instead of one ? What result did you expect ?

Comment: I added the description of a example above.

Comment: OK, did you try executing the native sql query generated, what does she return ?

Comment: ...uh ...it is different from the real DQL because it is simplified for the purpose of explanation. It is too many other related. However, since the problem is getting the data at once? A friend of child and parent can't treated separately? I edited the description of a example above.